# How can I run a python code on AWS EC2 and then use POST?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, post, amazon-ec2

lets say I have this code

```
s =int(input("Input a number "))

x = s+5 

print(x)
```

how do I run it on EC2 and then use flask to get the output using POST so I can use it on a front end ?

I want to make a webpage where a user can input s and then the backend which is an index.py file that communicates with AWS EC2 (using flask) to run the python code above and then return the value x to the front end

Comment: Could you please explain in detail what do you want to do?.

Comment: I want to make a webpage where a user can input s and then the backend which is an index.py file that communicates with AWS EC2 (using flask) to run the python code above and then return the value x to the front end

Answer (score 0):

flask app sample code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from index import some_fun

app = Flask(_name_)


@app.route('/foo', methods=['POST'])
def foo():
    data = request.form.to_dict()
    function_response = some_fun(data['form_field'])
    print(function_response)
    return jsonify(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

You python script, index.py from where you want call some_function

`def some_fun(x): return x + 5`

here i have considered post request is of multipart/form-data.
if you are making post request with application/json
then

`data = request.json`

Comment: where does the link to the EC2 instance go in the code you provided ?

Comment: You want to make POST request from your python file or
You want to call python file from flask app once POST request is made. I have given solution for second. If you want first, then you need to use ' requests ' python package.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_post.asp